# change font color of selected text in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a `mouseUp` event listening to a div to notify when there is a text selection by user. I get the selected text by `window.getSelectoin().toString()` but i also want to mark that particular text by giving a font color but no idea how. Am unable to add a span to that particular selection range. Any idea how to achieve this?
Lets say i have div as below

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

So if a user selects some texts in it, i should mark it with some font color. The font color should stick the text permanently. So i cannot use ::Selection. Thanks in advance

Comment: Get that selected text, use Regular Expression to find the text in the entire div and add an opening span to the beginning and a closing span to the end. Then give it a class and select that class via css. On selecting other text, remove the old span and rinse and repeat

Comment: i cannot use regex because div can have duplicate/repeated texts. can we solve this?

Comment: You can use @Vivek Doshi's answer if you don't mind the text getting deselected when the user clicks somewhere else or selects another text block.

Comment: i cannot add class attributes to the div. And i want the text selection to be permenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a day long google-ing i was able to achieve this. In case any one need this in future :P What i did is - making the wrapper div with contentEditable true and used document.execCommand api to do the required customization. 
Note: i will however will not let user edit the content using preventDefault in below handlers

````
        onCut={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}
        onPaste={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}
        onKeyPress={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}
        onKeyDown={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}``` Thanks for helping
````

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is CSS and not any JS script for that :

You can use `::selection` property for that :

---

You can run the below snippet **[( Code Ref & Much more )](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/)** , Hope this will help you

```css
.example-color::selection {
  color: #8e44ad;
}
.example-background-color::selection {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.example-background::selection {
  background: #e74c3c;
}
.example-both::selection {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  color: white;
}
.example-shadow::selection {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #27ae60;
}
.example-input::selection {
  background: #2ecc71;
}
.example-textarea::selection {
  background: #34495e;
  color: white;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.45;
  background: #E0DCCC;
  color: #333;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

p,input,textarea  {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
input,textarea {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>Select me to see normal behavior.</p>
<p class='example-color'>Try selecting me for a different text color.</p>
<p class='example-background-color'>You can select me for a different background color.</p>
<p class='example-background'>You can also select me for a different background.</p>
<p class='example-both'>Guess what&hellip; you can select me for a different background color and text color.</p>
<p class='example-shadow'>How about a text-shadow? Sure, select me for a different text-shadow.</p>
<p class='example-background-color'>
  What about nest elements? Select me for a different background color.
  <span class='example-color'>And this sentence is just a color selection.</span>
  Nesting works!
</p>
<input class='example-input' type='text' value='Inputs work!*'>
<textarea class='example-textarea' cols='30' name='' rows='10'>Textarea, too!*</textarea>
<div class='foot-notes'>*not Safari</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly, as the div elements are dynamic- it doesn't contain any classes. there are just div elements or paragraphs.

Comment: you can apply that on div also without classname , you'll need just proper css element selection @LogeshR

Comment: I want the selected text color to be permanent. Is it possible?

Comment: @LogeshR, in that case you have lot of work to do, when user selects the text you have to put the selected text in span or any other tag with the style you want

Comment: yes, i have created a <span style="color: red">selected text here</span>. i just dont know to insert it back to the div on its selection.

Comment: @LogeshR, you can take ref from : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight-selection

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of CSS, don't go to JS if CSS can handle something.
Add this style in your stylesheet

```
::selection {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
 }
```